# How to use figure inside a minipage?

Tags: graphics, floats, minipage

I'm trying to include an image, and keep it centered, and prevent from wrapping from the next page.  The following code works for that:

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
        Caption for image

        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{myimage.png} 
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}
```

I'd like this image to be in a figure, with a caption.  The following doesn't compile:

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{myimage.png}
        \caption{Caption for image}
        \label{fig:sample_figure}
    \end{figure}
\end{minipage}
```

I get the errors:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
! Undefined control sequence.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `figure` is a *float*, it must be outside any other environment (not counting `document` of course). Also check [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

`Figure` is a floating environment and `minipage` is, unfortunately, *not*. Therefore, if you put a floating object inside a non-floating `minipage`, you will get an error. But the other way around is possible--you can put a `minipage` inside a `figure` environment:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=3.0in]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption for image}
    \label{fig:sample_figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Another method is to avoid using `figure` entirely. This can be done with help of the `caption` package (with its `captionof` facility, so that you can have a caption for the figure):

```
.....in preamble
\usepackage{caption}

......in document body

\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3.0in]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{Caption for image}
\label{fig:sample_figure}
\end{minipage}
```

The total mwe will be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe} % new package from Martin scharrer
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

 \begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
 \centering
        \includegraphics[width=3.0in]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Caption for image}
        \label{fig:sample_figure}
 \end{minipage}
 \end{figure}

 \noindent
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
        \includegraphics[width=3.0in]{example-image-a}
        \captionof{figure}{Caption for image}
        \label{fig:sample_figure}
 \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The result will be:

[image]

Comment: My first use of `mwe` package @Martinscharrer

Comment: Thanks for using it! Note that you can use the images without loading the package. Using `graphicx` here directly might actually be better.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Well, I am new to `mwe`. Slowly I hope to get accustomed to it. Thanks for a great package and also for the short cuts for CTAN packages and texdoc.net. They are very useful.

Comment: This is probably what the OP actually wants... bit it is in fact possible to do what the OP asks for. See my answer.

Answer (score 58):

You can put a figure inside a minipage if you use the "float" package. The following will put two figures side by side. If you caption them, the captions will be side by side.

```
\usepackage{float}

 ...

  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \centering
      \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
          \begin{figure}[H]
              \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/dummy}
              \caption{This is the first figure}
          \end{figure}
      \end{minipage}
      \hspace{0.05\linewidth}
      \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
          \begin{figure}[H]
              \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/dummy}
              \caption{This is the second figure}
          \end{figure}
      \end{minipage}
  \end{minipage}
```

[image: Two figures side by side using minipages]

Comment: This is great. It just needs to also align the captions when the images don't share their height

Comment: @ThomasAhle, better use subfigure package for that purpose.

Comment: hmm .. this didn't work for me.

Comment: @dementedhedgehog Did you notice the subtle use of the parameter `[H]` following the environment declaration of the figures?

Comment: I may have missed it... it was a while ago I can't go back and test.

Comment: For me the trick was to use the package pgf. I.e. `\usepackage{pgf}`.

Comment: This makes me both figures in one continuous column.

Answer (score 15):

You could try this for 2 figures side by side:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \subcaption{Image 1.}\label{fig:1}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \subcaption{Image 2.}\label{fig:2}
    \end{minipage}  
    \label{fig:1-2}
    \caption{Title.}
\end{figure}
```

[image: example 1]

Or this, for 3 figures side by side:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/1.png}
        \subcaption{Image 1.}\label{fig:1}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/2.png}
        \subcaption{Image 2.}\label{fig:2}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/rtk3.png}
        \subcaption{Image 3.}\label{fig:3}
    \end{minipage}  
    \label{fig:1-2-3}
    \caption{Title.}
\end{figure}
```

[image: example 2]

All minipages are aligned by the top of the figure once subcaptions could mess bottom alignment.