# Figure inside a minipage

Tags: floats, minipage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use figure inside a minipage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55337/how-to-use-figure-inside-a-minipage)

For a kind of report, I have to write each section in a boxed space.
To do that, I use the following :

```
\newcommand{\textbox}[1]{
\hfill
\centering
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
\vspace{0.2cm}
#1
\end{minipage}
\newline
}
\vspace{1cm}
}
```

And the use is simply :

```
\textbox{
    This is my first part.
}
\textbox{
    This is my second part.
}
```

How to put figures inside these boxes ?
If I try :

```
\textbox {
    This is my third part.
    \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=9cm]{myfigure.png}
    \vspace{-12pt}
    \caption{My caption.}
    \label{fig:myfigure}
    \end{figure} 
}
```

It fails with the following error : `LaTeX Error : Float(s) lost.`

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: You can not have a floating environment inside a non-floating box. So you can't have `figure` you can have `\includegraphics` and if you use the `capt-of` package you can have a labeled caption `\captionof{figure}{...`  Or you can just box the _contents_ of the figure and allow the box itself to float.

Comment: unrelated you need to put a `%` after every `{` and `}` in your definition otherwise the content is not centred in the box as you have varying numbers of word spaces either side. using `\hfill` and `\centering` together is rather odd.  They will counter-act each other just use `\centering and use `\par` not `\newline` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As told in the linked answer by lockstep, you can't put `figure` inside a `minipage` as the former is a float and latter is not. The solution is to define a separate `figurebox` in addition to `textbox` as shown in the MWE. Also you have to add `%` at appropriate places to avoid spurious spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\textbox}[1]{%
\par
\noindent
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}%
\vspace{0.2cm}
\centering
#1
\end{minipage}%
}
\vspace{1cm}
}%
%
\newcommand{\figurebox}[4]{%
\begin{figure}[htb]%
\fbox{%
\centering
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.95\textwidth}
\centering #1\par
    \includegraphics[width=3.0in]{#2}
    \caption{#3}
    \label{#4}
\end{minipage}%
}%
\end{figure}%
}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
\textbox{This is my first part.}%
\textbox{This is my second part.}
%% syntax is \figurebox{text}{figure file name}{caption}{label}
\figurebox{This is my third part}{example-image-a}{My figure}{fig:first}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Option -2**

If you want to use the same `textbox` command for figures also, then you have to avoid the float `figure` To get the captions you can use `caption` or `capt-of` packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,capt-of}
\newcommand{\textbox}[1]{%
\par
\noindent
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}%
\vspace{0.2cm}
\centering
#1
\end{minipage}%
}
\vspace{1cm}
}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
\textbox{This is my first part.}%
\textbox{This is my second part.}
\textbox {%
    This is my third part.
    \includegraphics[width=9cm]{example-image-a}
    \vspace{-12pt}
    \captionof{figure}{My caption.}
    \label{fig:myfigure}
}%



\end{document}
```