# How to put a figure inside a minipage when using memoir?

Tags: floats, memoir, minipage

I need to put a figure inside a minipage, like so:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{10cm}
  \begin{figure}
    blabla
    \caption{test}
  \end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

However, LaTeX doesn't like that since it is no longer in outer par mode, so it crashes and burns. I then tried the solution provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55337/2634), but that doesn't work either since the `float` package doesn't play nicely with `memoir`.

Is there a way of working around this?

Comment: Reversing the order of `minipage` and `figure` is not a good option?

Comment: why do you think you want to put a figure in the minipage? Either use minipage (you can use caption from capt-of package) or use figure, you can not use both.

Comment: Related: [How to use figure inside a minipage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55337)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot place a floating environment inside a `minipage`; if you want to place a caption for your image inside a `minipage`, you can use `memoir`'s `\newfixedcaption` command which provides captions outside floating environments:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newfixedcaption{\figcaption}{figure}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\centering
 A
\figcaption{test}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Another option would be to use `\captionof` from the `capt-of` package:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\centering
 A
\captionof{figure}{test}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The `caption` package also provides the `\captionof` functionality, but it might interfer with the way `memoir` handles its captions, so I opted for `capt-of`.

Comment: `memoir` also have stationary captions, but it is not enabled by default, see `\newfixedcaption` in the `memoir` manual

Comment: @daleif I thought I had seen this, but couldn't remember the name. I'll add this to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I had to look it up ...