# Add figures to a minipage

Tags: floats, lyx, minipage

I've been trying to add figures to a minipage in lyx but couldn't really find a way.
Does someone know how this is done in lyx?

Comment: Do you want to add `figures` or `graphics`? A `figure` is a floating environment I think you just want to use `\includegraphics` command inside the `minipage`.

Comment: what I exactly want to do is to add two figures side by side . I have been trying to add two minipages side by side and to insert floating figures to them. But that doesn't work.

Comment: Is this what you want? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95357/1952

Comment: yep, thanks mate. Do you have any idea how that's done in lyx?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used lyx.

Answer (score 2):

figured it out and it works perfect

1.insert figure float, insert>> float>>figure

2.add minipages inside the float, insert>> box>>frameless

3.right click on the minipage inserted and change width, right click on Box(minipage)>>settings>>width

4.Add horizontal space, insert>>formatting>>horizontal space

5.click on the horizontal space and change it to horizontal fill

6.add pictures to each minipage and insert caption below the picture

7.Delete the figure caption inserted through step 1

Comment: Thanks for posting back your answer! (many new users just abandon the question once they find the answer). This will help anyone else with the same question. One small point (apologies if it's too picky): in your last step, I believe that you actually deleting the "caption" and not the "figure number" although I agree that in LyX it shows "Figure X:".