# Shrink table with \adjustbox and handling booktabs margins

Tags: tables

I'm trying to shrink table to fit on a page (as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97505/shrink-table-to-fit-on-a-page-or-keep-it-as-it-is)) but code doesn't compile.
Also, my table has some tiny gaps in margins, how do I remove those?

My code:

```
\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{
\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|l|c|c|c|c|l|c|@{}}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Sub-Item}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Projeto}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Processos}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Valor individual por}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Quantidade}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Total}} \\ \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &  &  & \textbf{Projeto} & \textbf{Processo} &  &  \\ \midrule
        Serviço de medição & 1 & 4 &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} &  \\ \midrule
        Serviço de apoio a projeto & 1 & 4 &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &  \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{6}{|r|}{\textbf{Valor total}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Proposta de preço para item 1}
    \label{PropostaItem1}
\end{table}
}
```

Compiler outputs this:

```
Not in outer par mode. \begin{table}[!htbp]
Undefined control sequence. \begin{table}[!htbp]
Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{table}[!htbp]
Overfull \hbox (0.69336pt too wide) in paragraph
```

See the table without `\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}`:

[image: Output]

Comment: The argument of `\adjustbox` has to be the `tabular` environment, not the `table` environment.

Comment: Never use vertical rules when employing `booktabs` rules (`\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`).

Comment: This problem is very similar in nature to [How to use `figure` inside a `minipage`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55337/5764)

Comment: scaling a table to make it fit is so _horrible_ it just produces inconsistent font sizes. You do not justify paragraphs of text by arbitrarily scaling the text to make it fit, so why do that if the text happens to be in a table? It is far better to use a consistent documentclass font size such as `\small` if the text needs to be smaller.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The object that (potentially) has to be resized via `\adjustbox` is the `tabular` material, *not* the `table` environment.

Also, as @egreg has already pointed out in a comment, don't use vertical rules if you use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package. Actually, coming to think of it, don't use vertical rules at all, whether or not you use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package...

[image]

```
\documentclass[portuguese]{article} % or spanish?!
\usepackage{lmodern,babel,adjustbox,booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{%
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{6}{c}@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Sub-Item}}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Projeto}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Processos}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Valor individual por}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Quantidade}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Total}} \\ \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
 &  &  & \textbf{Projeto} & \textbf{Processo} \\ 
\midrule
Serviço de medição & 1 & 4 &  &  & 2 &  \\ %%\midrule
Serviço de apoio a projeto & 1 & 4 &  &  & 1 &  \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r}{\textbf{Valor total}} &  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Proposta de preço para item 1}
\label{PropostaItem1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* with two alternative specifications of some or all of the tabular material:

- If you're looking to give your table an cleaner and simpler, i.e., less turgid, look, don't use **bold**. I strongly suggest you (a) get rid of the **bold** font weights in the header cells and (b) dispense with the `\multirow` directives as well.
- Using `\adjustbox` to make the `tabular`-like material fit inside the width of the textblock "works", but only in an extremely narrow sense. What's wrong with the `\adjustbox` approach, from a typographic experience? Most importantly, you run the serious risk of reducing the font size so much as to make the table well-nigh illegible. Thus, instead of taking the mechanical approach, think about (a) using automatic line breaks and text wrapping in some of the columns, (b) reducing the amount of intercolumn whitespace, and (c) shortening the labels used in the header row. The second table below implements all three ideas. I hope you will agree that the result is far more readable than the compressed table above it is.

[image]

```
\documentclass[portuguese]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern,babel,adjustbox,booktabs,
            tabularx,ragged2e,xcolor}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangindent=1em \hangafter=1 \arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]

\textcolor{red}{A\@. tabular environment, compressed}

\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{6}{c}@{}}
\toprule
Sub-Item & Projeto & Processos & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Valor individual por} & Quantidade & Total \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
 &  &  & Projeto & Processo \\ 
\midrule
Serviço de medição & 1 & 4 &  &  & 2 &  \\ %%\midrule
Serviço de apoio a projeto & 1 & 4 &  &  & 1 &  \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r}{Valor total} &  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\bigskip
\textcolor{red}{B\@. tabularx environment, uncompressed}

\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default is 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}L*{6}{c}@{}}
\toprule
Sub-Item & Projeto & Processos & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Valor individual por} & Quant. & Total \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
 &  &  & Projeto & Processo \\ 
\midrule
Serviço de medição & 1 & 4 &  &  & 2 &  \\ %%\midrule
Serviço de apoio a projeto & 1 & 4 &  &  & 1 &  \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r}{Valor total} &  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In my opinion, a warning "Is this really something you want to do?"  of some kind would improve this answer. See David Carlisle's comment.

Comment: @RunarTrollet - Thanks for this. I've added a third example: a `tabularx` environment that manages to typeset the table without resorting to compression.