# Minipages in Springer template

Tags: floats, minipage, sv-classes

I'm using the [Springer svjour3 template](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svjour3/kernel/) and trying to put two figures in the same level with:

```
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}    % outer minipage
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,trim={3.5cm 7cm 3cm 6.6cm},clip]{histk1000.eps}
\caption{My caption}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,trim={3.5cm 7cm 3cm 6.6cm},clip]{histk1000.eps}
\caption{My caption}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{minipage}  % ending outer minipage
```

and it doesn't show figures. They appear if I remove the outer minipage. Any idea?

This is a (min) complete script:

```
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{xxcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, citecolor   = green]{hyperref}%pdftex,
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsbsy, amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx, caption}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[ msc-links]{amsrefs}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\usepackage{python}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
%
\begin{document}

\title{Efficient generator 
}

\author{Titus Caius
}


\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
% The correct dates will be entered by the editor


\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This work introduces ...
\end{abstract}

...


\begin{multicols}{2}

 \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth,trim={3.5cm 7cm 3cm 6.6cm},clip]{histk1000.eps}
\caption{My caption}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth,trim={3.5cm 7cm 3cm 6.6cm},clip]{histk1000.eps}
\caption{My caption}
\end{minipage}

\end{multicols}


\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}    % outer minipage

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth,trim={3.5cm 7cm 3cm 6.6cm},clip]{histk1000.eps}
\caption{My caption}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth,trim={3.5cm 7cm 3cm 6.6cm},clip]{histk1000.eps}
\caption{My caption}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{minipage}  % ending outer minipage

  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \centering
      \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{figure*}
              \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,trim={3.5cm 7cm 3cm 6.6cm},clip]{example.eps}
              \caption{Histogram of 1000000 numbers for $k=1000$; $n=100$}
                            \label{hist1}       % Give a unique label
\end{figure*}
      \end{minipage}
      \hspace{0.05\linewidth}
      \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
          \begin{figure*}[H]
              \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,trim={3.5cm 7cm 3cm 6.6cm},clip]{histk997.eps}
              \caption{Histogram of 1000000 numbers for $k=997$; $n=100$}
                            \label{hist2}
          \end{figure*}
      \end{minipage}
  \end{minipage}



      \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \centering
      \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
          \begin{figure*}[H]
              \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,trim={3.5cm 7cm 3cm 6.6cm},clip]{plot100.pdf}
              \caption{Plot of pairs $(x_j,x_{j+1})$ for $k=100$; 1000 generated numbers}
                            \label{fig:1}
          \end{figure*}
      \end{minipage}
      \hspace{0.05\linewidth}
      \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
          \begin{figure*}[H]
              \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,trim={3.5cm 7cm 3cm 6.6cm},clip]{plot109.pdf}
              \caption{Plot of pairs $(x_j,x_{j+1})$ for $k=109$; 1000 generated numbers}
                            \label{fig:2}
          \end{figure*}
      \end{minipage}
  \end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

I just want two show side by side like in the `multicols` environment. It works for `multicols` (no caption), but not with `minipage`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You're trying to take the floating environment as a prisoner inside a `minipage`. I suspect some messages like `floats lost` etc. there

Comment: Don't understand what you want. Maybe just two `minipage`s side by side in one `figure` instead of two `figure`s inside one `minipage`. Maybe even using package `subcaption` would be a suggestion. If not, [you should add a minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` and describe what you exactly except.

Comment: Related: [How to use figure inside a minipage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55337/how-to-use-figure-inside-a-minipage)

Comment: Off-Topic: You should not use `\usepackage{t1enc}` but `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. You should load `hyperref` as late as possible. You should not load packages more than once with different options. For a MWE you should reduce your preamble. And for a real MWE you should replace the image files, e.g., by `example-image` from [package `mwe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe), because we do not have your images and so the example is not a working one. See the link in my first comment.

Comment: Your code is not minimal.  Also you load many packages twice and do load `hyperref` last.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 1):

I solved like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[ msc-links]{amsrefs}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\usepackage{python}

\begin{document}

 \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
      \begin{figure}[H]
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
          \caption{This is the first figure}
      \end{figure}
  \end{minipage}
  \hspace{0.05\linewidth}
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
      \begin{figure}[H]
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
          \caption{This is the second figure}
      \end{figure}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like you have two accounts.  You should ask the moderators to merge them.  The fundamental approach above is wrong: `minipage`s don't float and should not contain floats.