# How to center a figure with two subfigures under an enumeration item?

Tags: floats, subfloats

I want to center my two subfigures under the enumeration item, while the figure output is just at the center of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{subfig}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 11111
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 

    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\subfloat[Even function:reflectional symmetry   \label{a}]%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=0.3\linewidth, ymax=2.5,ymin=-0.5]
    \addplot[domain=-5:5, color=red,samples=500]{cos(deg(x))+(cos(deg(x)))^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
    \hfil
\subfloat[Odd function: rotational symmetry \label{b}]%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=0.3\linewidth, ymax=1.5,ymin=-1.5]
    \addplot[domain=-3:3, color=red,samples=50]{0.1*x+(sin(deg(x)))^3};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
    \caption{ }
    \label{1}
    \end{figure}

\end{enumerate}

\item 22222
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

By using the code above, the output is
[image: my output]

I want it to be centered under the (a).

Like the picture below (made by Adobe PS)

[image]

*Part of the code was provided by @Zarko .

Comment: A figure is a floating environment. A minipage is not.

Comment: You can't have floats inside a `minipage` (and it doesn't make sense to do so either). What were you trying to achieve? Edit: Note also that the `subfigure` package is considered deprecated, and that using the features of either the `subfig` or `subcaption` package is recommended instead.

Comment: Thank you! @TorbjørnT. I want to center a figure with 2 subfigures under an intended item. How can I achieve

Comment: @Superfrankie, please clarify your question with extension of your code snippet to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...} and `end{document}`.

Comment: also have a look at [questions/55337](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55337).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as mentioned in above comments:

- floats had not be enclosed in `minipages` (or other environments)
- for sub figures and tables are available packages `sunfig (as used in *mwe* below) and`suncaption
- that sub figures you can fit in one line, the sum of their widths had to be smaller than text width (therefore i add `width=0.45\linewidth` to each axis declaration)
- red line only indicate page layout. `showframe` had to be removed in real document

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{subfig}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\subfloat[Even function:reflectional symmetry   \label{a}]%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=0.45\linewidth, ymax=2.5,ymin=-0.5]
    \addplot[domain=-5:5, color=red,samples=500]{cos(deg(x))+(cos(deg(x)))^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
    \hfil
\subfloat[Odd function: rotational symmetry \label{b}]%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=0.45\linewidth, ymax=1.5,ymin=-1.5]
    \addplot[domain=-3:3, color=red,samples=50]{0.1*x+(sin(deg(x)))^3};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
    \caption{ }
    \label{1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**addendum:**

after edited question is more clear where images should be:

[image]

are now correct positioned?

frame around image is only for show that images are now centered to enumerate list. in real document you should remove `\fbox` from code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{subfig}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 11111
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test

    \begin{figure}[ht]
\hfill\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\leftmargin-\leftmargini\relax}
    \centering
\subfloat[Even function: reflectional symmetry   \label{a}]%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=0.48\linewidth, ymax=2.5,ymin=-0.5]
    \addplot[domain=-5:5, color=red,samples=500]{cos(deg(x))+(cos(deg(x)))^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
    \hfil
\subfloat[Odd function: rotational symmetry \label{b}]%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=0.48\linewidth, ymax=1.5,ymin=-1.5]
    \addplot[domain=-3:3, color=red,samples=50]{0.1*x+(sin(deg(x)))^3};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
    \caption{ }
    \label{1}
    \end{minipage}
    }
    \end{figure}
\end{enumerate}

\item 22222
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to center my figure under an item of enumeration.

Comment: (i) in question you now use my code, but you give  credits to another (respectable) member of site (ii) your question is slightly more clear, bur it is still unknown, what you like to obtain. images start at left text border, images are so small, that can be centered below "a",  a list start at middle of text width? clarify, please.

Comment: Apology for my mistakes on the credits.

Comment: @Superfrankie, see if solution addendum to my answer is o.k.

Comment: Great! That's what I want. Thank you! But how to achieve this without borders....

Comment: @Superfrankie To remove the borders, just leave out `\fbox` (=framed box).

Comment: @Superfrankie, i mentioned in answer, that in real document you should remove `\fbox`. if answer fulfill your expectation, you can accept it :-).