# Two different versions for exam, solution file needs to have a figure. Float(s) lost error with current code

Tags: floats, conditionals, minipage

I'm writing an exam for my class. The problems file needs to have an empty box after each question, while the solutions file should have the solution (preferably in a different colour). I got the code to do this from [here](https://joel.porquet.org/wiki/hacking/latex_conditional_boxes/).

Unfortunately, this only works for those solutions that have only text/math in them. I also have figures, and that's throwing a "float(s) lost" error. Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,hyperref]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
% STUFF FOR SOLUTION ENVIRONMENT
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newenvironment{solution}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\teacher}}{%
        \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\hfill\vspace*{#1}\end{minipage}}%
    }{}%
    \newbox\tempbox%
    \begin{lrbox}{\tempbox}\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
}{%
    \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
    \ifthenelse{\not\isundefined{\teacher}}{%
        \medskip%
        \fbox{\usebox{\tempbox}}%
        \medskip%
    }{}%
}

\def\teacher{true} %comment this out for empty box (in student's version)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is the first problem on the test. \\
        \begin{solution}{5cm}
            This is the first solution. 
        \end{solution}

    \item This is the second problem. \\
        \begin{solution}{5cm}
            This is the second solutiuon.
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
            % COMMENT OUT FIGURE BELOW TO SEE IT WORK
                \begin{figure}[h]
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis} [
                height=5cm, width=7cm, xlabel={$t$}, ylabel={$x(t)$},
                xmin=-4, xmax=4, ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, no markers,
                xtick={-2.5, -.5, .5, 2.5}, ytick={1, -1},
                axis lines=middle
                ]
                \addplot[thick, black] coordinates {(-1, 0) (0, 1) (1, 0)};
                \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{Output signal for Problem 3a}\label{fig:samplefig}
                \end{figure}
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \end{solution}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not obvious how to use `figure` in a `minipage` environment, see [How to use figure inside a minipage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55337/how-to-use-figure-inside-a-minipage).

If you can avoid the figure environment, you can simply do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,hyperref]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
a%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
% STUFF FOR SOLUTION ENVIRONMENT
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newenvironment{solution}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\teacher}}{%
        \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\hfill\vspace*{#1}\end{minipage}}%
    }{}%
    \newbox\tempbox%
    \begin{lrbox}{\tempbox}\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
}{%
    \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
    \ifthenelse{\not\isundefined{\teacher}}{%
        \medskip%
        \fbox{\usebox{\tempbox}}%
        \medskip%
    }{}%
}

\def\teacher{true} %comment this out for empty box
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is the first problem on the test. \\
        \begin{solution}{5cm}
            This is the first solution. 
        \end{solution}

    \item This is the second problem. \\
        \begin{solution}{5cm}
            This is the second solutiuon.
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
            % COMMENT OUT FIGURE BELOW TO SEE IT WORK
                \begin{center}
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis} [
                    height=5cm, width=7cm, xlabel={$t$}, ylabel={$x(t)$},
                    xmin=-4, xmax=4, ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, no markers,
                    xtick={-2.5, -.5, .5, 2.5}, ytick={1, -1},
                    axis lines=middle
                    ]
                    \addplot[thick, black] coordinates {(-1, 0) (0, 1) (1, 0)};
                    \end{axis}
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                    {Output signal for Problem 3a}\label{fig:samplefig}
                \end{center}
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \end{solution}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting fact! I had no idea. This definitely fixes my problem right now. Thanks a lot!