# Missing \endcsname inserted., "relax" when inserting figures in minipage in newcommand

Tags: macros, floats

I am trying to insert figures in minipages in newcommands to get two images on a a5 paper. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[a5paper, margin=5mm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\twoimages}[2]{
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}
        \begin{figure}
            \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
               \includegraphics[width=0.97\textwidth]{#1}
            \end{minipage}
            \noindent
            \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
               \includegraphics[width=0.97\textwidth]{#2}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{figure}
    \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\twoimages{example-image-plain}{example-image-plain}
\end{document}
```

which results in

```
<to be read again>
                   \relax
l.21 ...{example-image-plain}{example-image-plain}
```

I cant spot the error. I got part of the code from [How to use figure inside a minipage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55337/how-to-use-figure-inside-a-minipage)
and I already tried `\DeclareRobustCommand`, but no luck.

Can you help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If you just want to include two images without a caption, there is no need for the `figure` environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The first `\begin{minipage}` is missing the mandatory `width` argument. However, a `figure` environment inside a `minipage` will raise yet another error...

Comment: @PatrickBateman  Seems you like the book of Bret Easton Ellis? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I overthought it. Thank you @leandriis and https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574/phelype-oleinik

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[a5paper, margin=5mm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\twoimages}[2]{
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=0.96\textwidth]{#1}
        \noindent
       \includegraphics[width=0.96\textwidth]{#2}
    \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\twoimages{example-image-plain}{example-image-plain}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the minipage here is doing nothing, you can delete it, similarly the `\noindent` command. The `\centering` command will apply to the whole document, perhaps that is OK but if your actual document has following text it will be centred.

Comment: Thank you, too!