# How to align the Figure title of two side by side images within enumerate function

Tags: enumerate, alignment

I have a latex document in which I have included two images side by side within an enumerate function. The caption for those individual figures is aligned to the figure itself, but the overall Figure title is not aligned with the enumerate function instead it is aligned with the rest of the document

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Consider the two figures given below,
\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
            \centering
            \subfloat[\centering Figure 1 title.]
            {
                {
                    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Figures/Figure_1.png}
                }
                \label{Figure_1}
            }
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
            \centering
            \subfloat[\centering Figure 2 title.]
            {
                {
                    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Figures/Figure_.png}
                }
                \label{fig:Figure_2}
            }
        \end{minipage}
        \caption{Common title for figure 1 and figure.}%
        \label{fig:fig:power_response}
    \end{figure}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: This is by design. The only function of the `figure` environment is to mark the content as not part of the document flow but an insert that can float and be inserted elsewhere so `figure` normalises margins, fonts, and some other settings to ensure they are not inherited from the position in the source.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use or nest the `\subcaption` package, inside the enumerate function, to align subfloats within a single float.

I am trying to figure out the output of your example, meanwhile you can
have a look at the following thread in TSE: [How to Use  Figure Inside a Minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55337/how-to-use-figure-inside-a-minipage)

or: [Floats, Figures and Captions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats)

I'm following.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

- Your question is not clear at all... :

  - how should `enumerate` influence on figure,
  - are you aware that float `figure` can move out of enumerate or at least to some other item? Is this your problem?
  - which package you use for `\subfloat`,
  - why `\subfloat` should in inside of `\minipage`s,
  - what result you expected,
  - etc.

A simple example how can be written your code fragment is (without bothering with eventual problems with inserting figures into `enumerate` environment):

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Consider the two figures given below,
    \begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{Figures/Figure_1.png}
    \caption{Figure 1 title.}    
    \label{Figure_1}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{Figures/Figure_1.png}
    \caption{Figure 2 title.}
    \label{Figure_2}
\end{subfigure}
        \caption{Common title for figure \ref{Figure_1} and figure \ref{Figure_2}.}%
        \label{fig:fig:power_response}
    \end{figure}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

where instead of  `minipage` is used `subfigure` environment defined in the `subcaption` package. This MWE (Minimal Working Example) produce:

[image]

(red lines indicate part of page layout)

If you prefer to use of `subfloat` environment, you still can use `subcaption` package, but it should be of version 1.3 or newest. In this case the MWE body is:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Consider the two figures given below,
    \begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.4\linewidth}
\subfloat[Figure 1 title.   \protect\label{Figure_1}]%
    {\includegraphics{Figures/Figure_1.png}}
    \hfil
\subfloat[Figure 2 title.   \protect\label{Figure_2}]%
    {\includegraphics{Figures/Figure_2.png}}

\caption{Common title for figure \ref{Figure_1} and figure \ref{Figure_2}.}%
\label{fig:fig:power_response}
    \end{figure}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Result of compilation is the same as before.

However, Use of `minipage`s has sense when you like to have two parallel figures in one `figure` environment. In such cases, the MWE body can be

```
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Consider the two figures given below,
    \begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{Figures/Figure_1.png}
    \caption{Figure 1 title.}    
    \label{Figure_1}
\end{minipage}
    \hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{Figures/Figure_1.png}
    \caption{Figure 2 title.}
    \label{Figure_2}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Here you should be aware, the common caption for both figures now has no sense, so it is here drop out. Compilation result is:

[image]

So, still remains the main problem: what you after? Let us know!